# Where to buy graphics for cheap that I can use in work that I sell?

Tags: stock-images, resource-recommendations

I am making my own cards to sell, however, I would like to use some graphics and or backgrounds once in a while without having to make them all the time.

Where is the best place to buy graphics, images and backgrounds for a low cost that I can use in some of my cards that I will be selling?

Sometimes I just need to add one image or graphic and would like to purchase some but not sure where I can get them  so that I can use them in a card that I will sell.

Comment: any stock site give you the opportunity to buy graphics with very low rates. i.e. shutterstock.com

Comment: @Ilan most stock sites have restrictions on print on demand use, which is what it sounds like Nicki is after. If they do allow POD use, the prices are considerably higher.

Answer (score 3):

[**Creative Market**](https://creativemarket.com/) is designed for just this purpose. There are a lot of great resources from designers looking to capitalize on their creative overflow.

[**Veer**](http://www.veer.com/) has been around longer. It's more of a standard stock art site. If you remember EyeWire from years long past, these are the guys.

Comment: Wow, read the terms of Creative Market. It may be a great service for buyers, but sheesh.. do they take EVERYTHING if you're a contributor.

Comment: Pretty much. You won't find my extras there ;)

Comment: Side note: Creative Market is from the same guys that created [Colour Lovers](http://www.colourlovers.com/).