# Is there a colorspace atlas available in stock somewhere?

Tags: color-spaces

There are lots of pictures of an RGB colorspace atlas designed by Tauba Auerbach: http://www.designboom.com/art/tauba-auerbach-rgb-colorspace-atlas/.
I wonder if there are such things in stock somewhere? I don't mean authors originals but probably there are some analogues? Maybe it's called something another than "colorspace atlas".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about resource gathering, not design.

Comment: @Scott I'm sorry, I actually tried to consider whether it is related or not and finally searched for "buy". There are some topics like this one http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29588. Nevertheless of course I won't mind this question to be removed. Can you advise a suitable StackExchange branch for this? Or there is no such?

Comment: Apologies but there isn't a site for resource gathering that exists.  All I can advise is possibly consult someone on a design forum.